# How to add/remove user from own roster in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I would like to be able to handle user roster (add/remove buddy) without using xmpp stanzas, but with erlang own erlang function (or ejabberd functions).

Use case: i want to add `user2@myhost` to `user1@myhost`'s roster:

Is it possible to do something like:

```
User1 = "user1@myhost",
User2 = "user2@myhost",
mymodule:add_user_to_roster(User1, User2)
```

and if so, how can I implement the function `add_user_to_roster(User1, User2)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_roster functions, in particular https://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/devdoc/trunk/mod_roster.erl.html#process_subscription-6

Answer (score 0):

you can use a library such as libstrophe to implement the functionality.
but it does

Comment: thanks for you suggestion, but i was thinking to some erlang function related to mnesia